# How to get hour , week and quarter from datetime in Derived Colum Transformation Editor

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis, business-intelligence

I am creating an Integration Services Project in Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013. I want to convert a column of source table into different fields which I can send to different columns of a destination table. The transform which I am using is 'Derived Colum Transformation Editor', and I want to convert datetime type column of source into hours, day, week and quarter. I have successfully converted the column into types day, month and year by using these expressions

```
DAY( [DateTimeAssessment]  )
MONTH( [DateTimeAssessment]  )
YEAR( [DateTimeAssessment]  )
```

But how will I convert this column i.e. DateTimeAssessment, a datetime type column to hour, week and quarter?

thanks

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `datepart`

```
SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER, DateTimeAssessment)  -> Quarter
SELECT DATEPART(week, DateTimeAssessment)  -> Week
SELECT DATEPART(hour, DateTimeAssessment)  -> Hour
```

Comment: I am writing DATEPART( hour, [DateTimeAssessment]  ) in expression field in Derived Column Transformation Editor, and it is highlighted in red! It is not working.

Comment: @FarazAhmad, use "hour" ( in double quotes) . msdn mentions it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did DATEPART( "hour", [DateTimeAssessment] ), DATEPART( "week", [DateTimeAssessment] ) and DATEPART( "quarter", [DateTimeAssessment] ). Now it is working!

Comment: Here is the SSIS DATEPART URL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137586.aspx